# Checking if a tree is binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am not able to understand how the Java function [HERE](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html) (Please scroll to the very end of the page) checks if a tree is BST or not, as the code does not look like making using of min and max at all. 
I am copy pasting the code here as well

```
/** 
 Tests if a tree meets the conditions to be a 
 binary search tree (BST). Uses the efficient 
 recursive helper. 
*/ 
public boolean isBST2() { 
 return( isBST2(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE) ); 
}
/** 
  Efficient BST helper -- Given a node, and min and max values, 
  recurs down the tree to verify that it is a BST, and that all 
  its nodes are within the min..max range. Works in O(n) time -- 
  visits each node only once. 
*/ 
private boolean isBST2(Node node, int min, int max) { 
  if (node==null) { 
    return(true); 
  } 
  else { 
   // left should be in range  min...node.data 
    boolean leftOk = isBST2(node.left, min, node.data);

    // if the left is not ok, bail out 
    if (!leftOk) return(false);

    // right should be in range node.data+1..max 
    boolean rightOk = isBST2(node.right, node.data+1, max);

    return(rightOk); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Code has isBST2() method :P. It is just that checking min max conditions is missed out.

Comment: " A better solution looks at each node only once. The trick is to write a utility helper function isBSTRecur(struct node* node, int min, int max) that traverses down the tree keeping track of the narrowing min and max allowed values as it goes, looking at each node only once. The initial values for min and max should be INT_MIN and INT_MAX -- they narrow from there. "

Comment: @DavidPostill Right, although the syntax there is C, not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree is a BST if and only if the nodes of an inorder traversal are monotonic. The easiest way to think of this is that if the root has value *n*, then the left-hand branch should also be a BST whose nodes are at most *n*, and the right-hand side should be a BST whose nodes are at least *n*. If those conditions are satisfied then the tree as a whole is a BST.

That's exactly what your code **nearly** does. It checks that a tree is a BST with a given minimum a given maximum. It recursively calls itself by looking at the root node with value *data*, and then checks that the left-hand branch is a BST none of whose nodes exceeds *data*, and that the right-hand branch is a BST none of whose nodes is smaller than *data*.

But actually it doesn't quite do this... it misses out the min/max check! Perhaps you're supposed to add that yourself? Is this homework?

The place to add it would be in here:

```
if (node==null) { 
  return(true); 
}
```

You just need a couple of extra conditions for if `node!=null`...

Comment: Where is the code which checks "none of whose nodes exceeds data, and that the right-hand branch is a BST none of whose nodes is smaller than data."

Comment: @Andy897 sorry, that's the perils of posting while I was still editing... it doesn't do that bit. I'm guessing you're supposed to add it.

Comment: Lol. No. I am too old to do home works. :) .. I found this on *Stanford* website.  :P Link shared in post

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean checkBST(Node root) {
    return  c(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}

boolean c(Node n, int s, int b) {
    return n == null || (n.data > s && n.data < b && c(n.left, s, n.data) && c(n.right, n.data, b));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.